# Ideas for creating a generic method for multiple DataContext

Tags: c#, generics, wcf-data-services

I have the need to create a generic method to retrieve a specific kind of class that derives from `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext`, I got some ideas how to deal with this but so far I'm stuck in the concept of generic co-variance, does this concept applies to this case at all? this is how my current code looks like :

```
public abstract class BaseODataProvider<T> where T : DataServiceContext, new()
{
    public IApiSettings ApiSettings { get; set; }

    public BaseODataProvider(IApiSettings ApiSettings = null)
    {
        this.ApiSettings = ApiSettings ?? new DefaultApiSettings();
    }

    public T GetContext()
    {
        var context = new T(new Uri(ApiSettings.ODataUrl));
        context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
        context.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
        var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ApiSettings.LoginName + ":" + ApiSettings.Password));
        context.SendingRequest +=
                (object s, SendingRequestEventArgs e) =>
                        e.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
        return context;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no way I can instantiate T with optional parameters, it says "`cannot provide parameters when creating an instance of a type parameter 'T'`", however I would like to find out a way to resolve what URI is needed to create the oDataContext based on the type of `T`, so my expected instances would be something like this:

```
GetContext<MyContext1>().Table1.Where(x=>x.Id == 1);
GetContext<MyContext2>().Table2.FirstOrDefault();
```

Any help works!

Comment: What would you like us to do? As you said there is no way to use constructor with parameters on generic type.

Comment: I would like you guys to advice if there is a workaround for this problem, not only for the "new() constraint" restriction, Is there a way to create an instance of T using Lambda Expressions? again, with parameters in the ctor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate an object of a generic type with parameters using reflection.

```
public T GetContext()
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri(ApiSettings.ODataUrl);

    Type contextType = typeof(T);
    DataServiceContext context = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(contextType, myUri);

    // Do whatever

    return context;
}
```

The second argument of `Activator.CreateInstance` is an array of type `object`, so you can pass in whatever number or type of arguments the constructor requires.  To make the above code work, all of the `T` types you use have to have a constructor with the same signature, like this:

```
public class MyContext1 : DataServiceContext
{
    public MyContext1(Uri uri)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
}

public class MyContext2 : DataServiceContext
{
    public MyContext2(Uri uri)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

You're not limited to a single parameter either - this works for constructors with any number of parameters.  Just make sure that you're using the same number and type of arguments for each class that you instantiate this way.